# Sort collection by eager load value

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I've a `brand` table, `models` table, `categories` table.

`brand` have `hasMany` relation with `models`, `models` has `belongsTo` relation to `brand`, `categories` has `belongsToMany` relation with `models` table. Everything works fine.

Now, how can I get all models of a brand within a specific category?

I've tried this:

```
$categories = Category::with(['models'=>function($query) use ($brand_name){
            $query->with(['brand'=>function($query) use ($brand_name){
                $query->where('name', $brand_name);
            }]);
        }])->where('name', 'presses')->first();
```

But it has the same effect as of selecting all models within a specific category. It's not filtering the brand name.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you give an example of the specific category. What am seeing is brand_name but not category name

Comment: @oseintow category name would be `presses` -> the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let see how it goes

```
$categories = Category::with(['models'=>function($query) use ($brand_name){
     $query->whereHas('brand', function($query) use ($brand_name){
         $query->where('name', $brand_name);
     });
 },'models.brand'])->where('name', 'presses')->first();
```

Comment: This works. Awesome. So, `whereHas` can collect another eager load ?

Comment: Did you made any edit to this? seems this is not working

Comment: then let me revert it